# Can knockout.js use templates to generate templates?

Tags: javascript, jquery-templates, knockout.js

I'm trying to use knockout to templates to generate templates.

Along the lines of

Html:

```
<script id="searchField-template" type="text/html">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</script>

<script id="template-template"  type="text/html">
    <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'searchField-template', foreach: ${name} }" ></ul>
</script>
```

JS:

```
var viewModel = {
    Title: [{
        name: "Title1"},
    {
        name: "Title2"},
    {
        name: "Title3"}],
    Manager: [{
        name: "Manager1"},
    {
        name: "Manager2"},
    {
        name: "Manager3"}],

    Defn: [{
        name: "Title"},
    {
        name: "Manager"}]

};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

runnable sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/scottwww/yQZUE/2/

It seems that the problem is with how curly braces are interpreted.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go >

http://jsfiddle.net/vwP3w/2/

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is the right way, but a reference to the vm helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/scottwww/vwP3w/1/

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'template-template', foreach: Defn }"></div>

<script id="searchField-template" type="text/html">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</script>

<script id="template-template"  type="text/html">
    <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'searchField-template', foreach: vm[$data.name] }" ></ul>
</script>
```

JS:

```
var viewModel = {
    Title: [{
        name: "Title1"},
    {
        name: "Title2"},
    {
        name: "Title3"}],
    Manager: [{
        name: "Manager1"},
    {
        name: "Manager2"},
    {
        name: "Manager3"}],

    Defn: [{
        name: "Title"},
    {
        name: "Manager"}]

};
window.vm = viewModel;
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `$data` variable inside the nested template.

http://jsfiddle.net/dwick/yQZUE/3/

Comment: the template works fine.  it's the viewmodel that's incorrect.  what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: You are passing `Defn` in the outer template and it prints the the two names 'Title' and 'Manager' . It works fine. Do you want to print EVERY name of each item in the View Model ? That'll require to change the viewModel a bit.

Comment: @nEEbz - yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do - create a template that gets applied to 'Title' and 'Manager' so the the titles and managers are templatized